# NextJS application error in production: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')" only in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, use-effect, vercel

I am using the useEffect hook in a functional component to initialize the state of an upvote and notification button. When the page loads it fetches the user and when user is updated the useEffect hook sets the appropriate states. The problem is in production it throws a TypeError for these lines:

```
for (var i = 0; i < user.upvoted.length; i++) {
  if (user.upvoted.includes(project.id)) setIsUpvoted(true);
}
for (var i = 0; i < user.notifications.length; i++) {
  if (user.notifications.includes(project.id)) setIsNotified(true);
}
```

It says that the user.upvoted and user.notifications properties are undefined even though my code checks to make sure that user is defined before it runs the 2 for loops above. I even decided to check this by adding:

```
if (user) {
  console.log(user.upvoted.length);
}
```

right above and outside the useEffect hook. The console logs a value of 2 for the length of user.upvoted in the code above but still throws the undefined type error in the for loops. This only occurs in production and functions normally in dev and my IDE does not throw a type error in the code. Full code below:

```
export default function Project({ project }) {

  const [isUpvoted, setIsUpvoted] = useState(false);
  const [isNotified, setIsNotified] = useState(false);

  interface User {
    id: string;
    address: string;
    name: string;
    bio: string;
    upvoted: [string];
    notifications: [string];
    image: string;
    banner: string;
    links: {
      twitter: string;
      website: string;
      instagram: string;
      islands: string;
      opensea: string;
      discord: string;
    };
  }

  const { userCtx, showSignInModalCtx } = useContext(UserContext);
  const [user, setUser]: [User, any] = userCtx;
  const [showSignInModal, setShowSignInModal] = showSignInModalCtx;

  if (user) {
    console.log(user.upvoted.length);
  }

  // If the user is connected, sync their upvoted & notified projects
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      for (var i = 0; i < user.upvoted.length; i++) {
        if (user.upvoted.includes(project.id)) setIsUpvoted(true);
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < user.notifications.length; i++) {
        if (user.notifications.includes(project.id)) setIsNotified(true);
      }
    } else {
      setIsUpvoted(false);
      setIsNotified(false);
    }
  }, [user]);

  return <PageMarkup/>
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(user)` or `console.log(user.upvoted)` log inside the useEffect? Are you defaulting `user.upvoted` to an empty array in your context initial state?

Comment: user is initialized to null and then gets fed the entire object including the upvoted property from a graphql response. I fixed the issue by splitting the for loops into their own if statements "if (user & user.upvoted)" and "if (user & user.notifications)" because doing "if (user & user.upvoted & user.notifications)" never runs. I don't really understand why but it works. Thanks.